# 404 in google referencement - google site links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

My website is developed in REACTJS, when tryin to search the site, i found that google adds the 404 in the site links that appears under the first site search.

you can see that in the picture below :
[image]

How can i resolve that so that the 404 page do it does not show in the site links.

Thanks

I did not find a solution for this as i have to implement a 404 error page on the site .

Answer (score 1):

it will only appearing to you based on your history, it is coming on top because you visited it recenlty, if you want to remove it , you can add 404 page link into robots.txt file or if you have sitemap.xml file , remove 404 link from that